# Dynamic message in SQL with IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, qsqlquery

I am cross-validating two databases. I require to print a statement in messages based on the output.

When I am changing the local variable, for example, 'QLD' to 'QLDTS', the message was supposed to change, but it is not.

Please suggest a possible solution to the query.

Script is as below:

```
DECLARE @DestStageTableName VARCHAR(250) = 'Noofchildren'
, @DestStageSchema VARCHAR(250) = 'QLD'
, @snapshot VARCHAR(250) = '[[QLD_5_20191118_Dev]]'

SELECT * FROM meta.dbo.vDDS_STTMismatch
WHERE stttablename = @DestStageTableName
AND sttschema = @DestStageSchema
ORDER BY dbSort_Order

IF stttablename <> @DestStageTableName 
    PRINT N'The dest schema and tablename is different than stt';
ELSE 
    PRINT N'The following  table contains results';

GO
```

Comment: Oracle or SQL Server? Stored procedures language syntax varies between RDBMSs.

Comment: It is on SQL server. Thanks.

Comment: What's `stttablename`? If it's SQL Server, that can't be a variable....

Comment: you want to check schema or table name of the variable and your table ???

Comment: if i unerstand your problem correctly this code can help you `IF (not exists (
SELECT 1 FROM meta.dbo.vDDS_STTMismatch
WHERE stttablename = @DestStageTableName
AND sttschema = @DestStageSchema
ORDER BY dbSort_Order
))
begin
    PRINT N'The dest schema and tablename is different than stt';
end
ELSE
begin 
    PRINT N'The following  table contains results';
end`